# Quicksort Assembly MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, quicksort

I have this so far, but its printing out all 4's. And it is not sorted.

```
# Quicksort.asm

.data
array:      .word  4, 9, 12, -5, 2, 54, 8 , 1
line:       .asciiz  " "

.text
main:

    addi  $sp, $sp, -4       # Push the stack pointer down to hold one value
    sw    $ra, 0 ($sp)       # Store the return address on the stack
    la    $a0, array         # Array into a0
    addi  $a1, $zero, 0      # Left most element (p)
    addi  $a2, $zero, 7      # Right most element (r)   
    jal   quicksort

    addi  $t0, $zero, 0     # Counter loop
    addi  $t1, $zero, 8     # where the loop ends
    la    $t7, array       # loads base address of array into t7

topprintloop:

    beq  $t0, $t1, endprintloop

    sll  $t3, $t0, 2          # calculates j * 4
    addi $t3, $t7, 0          # Calculates the address of array[j]
    lw   $t4, 0($t3)          # load value at array[j]

    addi $v0, $zero, 1     # sets v0 to 1 for syscall
    addi $a0, $t4, 0       # load int to print into a0
    syscall                # prints it

    addi $v0, $zero, 4     # sets v0 to 4 for syscall
    la   $a0, line         # loads string to print into a0
    syscall              # prints it

    addi $t0, $t0, 1       # increment counter by 1
    j topprintloop         # jumps to topprintloop

endprintloop:

    lw    $ra, 0 ($sp)       # Restore the return address from the stack
    addi  $sp, $sp,  4       # Pop the stack 
    jr    $ra


quicksort:

    addi $sp, $sp, -20     # Store it to the stack
    sw   $ra, 0  ($sp)
    sw   $s0, 4  ($sp)
    sw   $s1, 8  ($sp)
    sw   $s2, 12 ($sp)
    sw   $s3, 16 ($sp)    
    addi $s0, $a0, 0        # store into s0 array pointer
    addi $s1, $a1, 0        # store into s1 left most element (p)
    addi $s2, $a2, 0        # store into s2 right most element (r)
                            # store into s3 q
    blt  $s1, $s2, prep    # jumps and links to prep if p < r
    j returnQuicksort      # jumps to returnQuicksort when finished

prep:

    addi $a0, $s0, 0       # store into s0 array pointer
    addi $a1, $s1, 0       # store into s1 left most element (p)
    addi $a2, $s2, 0       # store into s2 right most element (r)
    jal partition 
    addi $s3, $v0, 0       # stores the partition value of v0 and puts it into q
    # First recursive call
    addi $a0, $s0, 0       # store into a0 new left subarray 
    addi $a1, $s1, 0       # [p]
    addi $a2, $s3, -1      # [q-1]
    jal quicksort 

    # Second recursive call
    addi $a0, $s0, 0       # store into a0 new right subarray 
    addi $a1, $s3, 1       # [q+1]
    addi $a2, $s2, 0       # [r]    
    jal quicksort 


returnQuicksort:

    lw   $ra, 0  ($sp)     # pop the stack
    lw   $s0, 4  ($sp)
    lw   $s1, 8  ($sp)
    lw   $s2, 12 ($sp)
    lw   $s3, 16 ($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 20 
    jr $ra


partition:

    addi $sp, $sp, -28    # Push stack pointer
    sw   $ra, 0  ($sp) 
    sw   $s0, 4  ($sp)
    sw   $s1, 8  ($sp)
    sw   $s2, 12 ($sp)
    sw   $s3, 16 ($sp)
    sw   $s4, 20 ($sp)
    sw   $s5, 24 ($sp)

    addi $s0, $a0, 0       # Array pointer
    addi $s1, $a1, 0       # P value
    addi $s2, $a2, 0       # R value
    sll  $t0, $s2, 2       # * 4 into t0
    add $t1, $t0, $s0     
    lw   $s3, 0($t1)       # Pivot value
    addi $s4, $s1, -1      # value i 
    addi $s5, $s1, 0       # value j 


beginloop:

    bge  $s5, $s2, endloop    # j < r
    sll  $t0, $s5, 2          # * 4 into t0
    add  $t1, $t0, $s0     
    lw   $s3, 0($t1)          # Pivot value
    sll  $t2, $s5, 2
    add  $t2, $s0, $t2 
    lw   $t2, 0($t2)
    ble  $t2, $s3, doloop
    j loop

doloop:

    sll  $t0, $s5, 2          # calculates j * 4
    addi $t0, $s0, 0          # Calculates the address of array[j]
    lw   $t1, 0($t0)          # load value at array[j]
    ble  $t1, $s3, partitionswap  # branch if array[j] <= pivot
    j loop                   # skip partition swap if condition fails and go to loop

partitionswap:

    addi $s4, $s4, 1   #increment i
    addi $a0, $s0, 0   # load array into a0
    addi $a1, $s4, 0   # load i into a1
    addi $a2, $s5, 0   # load j into a2

    jal swap # we swap  

    j loop

loop:

    addi $s5, $s5, 1    # increments j (j++)
    j beginloop

endloop:

     # call swap
     addi  $t0, $s4, 1    # i+1
     addi  $a0, $s0, 0
     addi  $a1, $t0, 0    
     addi  $a2, $s2, 0
     jal swap
     addi  $t0, $s4, 1    
     addi  $v0, $t0, 0 
     lw   $ra, 0  ($sp) 
     lw   $s0, 4  ($sp)
     lw   $s1, 8  ($sp)
     lw   $s2, 12 ($sp)
     lw   $s3, 16 ($sp)
     lw   $s4, 20 ($sp)
     lw   $s5, 24 ($sp)
     addi $sp, $sp, 28    # Push stack pointer   

     jr $ra

swap:

    addi  $sp, $sp, -28    # Push the stack pointer down to hold seven values
    sw    $ra, 0 ($sp)      # Store the return address and s registers on the stack
    sw    $s0, 4 ($sp)
    sw    $s1, 8 ($sp)
    sw    $s2, 12($sp)
    sw    $s3, 16($sp)
    sw    $s4, 20($sp)
    sw    $s5, 24($sp)

    # Done with protecting registers. Now for the real work:
    sll   $s0, $a1, 2       # from * 4 into $s0
    sll   $s1, $a2, 2       # to * 4 into $s1
    add   $s2, $a0, $s0     # Address of array[from] into $s2
    add   $s3, $a0, $s1     # Address of array[ to] int9 $s3
    lw    $s4, 0($s2)       # Value of array[from] into $s4
    lw    $s5, 0($s3)       # Value of array[to] into $s5
    sw    $s4, 0($s3)       # Value from $s4 into array[to]
    sw    $s5, 0($s2)       # Value from $s5 into array[from]

    # Done with the work. No return value.
    lw    $ra, 0 ($sp)      # Restore the $ra and $s registers from the stack
    lw    $s0, 4 ($sp)
    lw    $s1, 8 ($sp)
    lw    $s2, 12($sp)
    lw    $s3, 16($sp)
    lw    $s4, 20($sp)
    lw    $s5, 24($sp)
    addi  $sp, $sp, 28      # Pop the stack pointer

    jr $ra
```

Comment: What is your question? I'm guessing that you're using SPIM/MARS. They have debugging features that e.g. let you step through your code. I suggest that you start by analyzing what's happening in your program at runtime.